# Get roles of a user in certain portal dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

i have a dotnetnuke with two portals that share users into 2 portals.

i want get roles of user A in portal 1 in a module in portal 2(in another portal)

how can i do that?

Comment: If you have UserID and PortalID you can use UserInfo ui = UserController.GetUser, ui.Roles, can you explain a little more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int portalId = 1;    
UserInfo user = UserController.GetUserById(portalid, UserID);
```

You can get the list of roles for a user in a specific portal using array: user.Roles or you can check if the user is in a specific role using: user.IsInRole(roleName).